# Serving local OSM tiles (PNG) using geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, tiles, offline

I downloaded OSM Local tiles for **offline** use. I am developing a web Application using Geoserver and Leaflet. My questions:

Is there a way to deploy **my local tiles** into **Geoserver**? And what about **performance** and caching management?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that, someone would have to write a GWC TileLayer similar to [ArcGisCache](https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/tree/master/geowebcache/arcgiscache) and then maybe also add a way to configure it from UI (e.g., going back to ArcGisCache, right now afaik you have to manually add the jar to the GeoServer, then manually change the GWC configuration file on disk, and force GeoServer to reload the config).

It certainly would be a welcomed improvement, I see this kind of question popping up every now and then.

Comment: Thanks @Andrea for your reply, So my question now, if this is not possible what are my best options to serve OSM local tiles and what's the best approach for good rendering performance ? 
Thanks!

Comment: That would be a separate question :-)